# Email app disappeared and now I can't access email

Tags: iphone, applications, email

I restored my home screen layout to factory settings after my email app disappeared, but now I cannot access my email. It just shows options to add accounts such as outlook etc. and then says the account already exists when I try to log in.

[image: Welcome to Mail]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Swipe down from the very top of your home screen. Type "mail" into the search field at the top of the screen. if the mail.app does not show up you may have accidentally deleted it. This is also an easy fix.

Go into the App Store, tap on search and type "mail app" look for the familiar icon and make sure the developer is "Apple." You can then "re-install the app like you would any other. There will be no charge to do this. This is merely the way Apple decided how to put back icons that you have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit simple, but try opening Settings, going into the Mail pane, then tapping accounts. Please ensure you have Mail turned on within Accounts that are required to get mail.